# Why display single data multiple times in table? jQuery loop ssue

Tags: jquery

My database only contain every data only once time. I am using jQuery for displaying data into html table it repeated. Check my code I think I have an issue in loop.

Database screen shot https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eog63.jpg

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : 'check.php',
        success: function (data) {

        data = $.parseJSON(data);
            var html = "";

        for(var a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
          console.log(a);
            var firstName = data[a].first_name;
            var email = data[a].email;
            var dob = data[a].dob;
            var country = data[a].country;          
            var gender = data[a].gender;
            var meal= data[a].meal;
            var img = data[a].profile_pic;
            var doc = data[a].resume;

            var array = img.split(',');
             b = 1;
            html += "<tr id=" +a+ ">";
                html += "<td>" + firstName + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + email + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + dob + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + country + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + gender + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + meal + "</td>";
              html += "<td>";
                 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                        var src = "uploads/"+ array[i];
                        var img1 = '<img src='+ src +' height="42" width="42">';
                         html += img1
                   }
            html += "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + doc + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + '<input type="submit" class="button" name="edit" value="Edit" />' + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + '<input type="submit" class="button" name="delete" value="Delete" />' + "</td>";
            html += "</tr>";
            b++;
           document.getElementById("data").innerHTML += html;
          }
        }
```

Comment: You have added the same screenshot twice

Comment: ==> Database screen shot https://imgur.com/a/3QNsNUe

Comment: Satpal thanks I get answer. issues Clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating the `innerHTML` in the `for` loop so, either move `document.getElementById("data").innerHTML += html;` outside loop or reinitialise `html` variable i.e. `html = ""` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

the problem should be the html string var, put it inside the  for(var a = 0; a < data.length; a++), so your code should be:

```
$.ajax({
        url : 'check.php',
        success: function (data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);


        for(var a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
            var html = "";
            console.log(a);
            var firstName = data[a].first_name;
            var email = data[a].email;
            var dob = data[a].dob;
            var country = data[a].country;          
            var gender = data[a].gender;
            var meal= data[a].meal;
            var img = data[a].profile_pic;
            var doc = data[a].resume;

            var array = img.split(',');
             b = 1;
            html += "<tr id=" +a+ ">";
                html += "<td>" + firstName + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + email + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + dob + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + country + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + gender + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + meal + "</td>";
              html += "<td>";
                 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                        var src = "uploads/"+ array[i];
                        var img1 = '<img src='+ src +' height="42" width="42">';
                         html += img1
                   }
            html += "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + doc + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + '<input type="submit" class="button" name="edit" value="Edit" />' + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + '<input type="submit" class="button" name="delete" value="Delete" />' + "</td>";
            html += "</tr>";
            b++;
           document.getElementById("data").innerHTML += html;
          }
        }`enter code here`
```